How to set context to ProcessPoolExecutor in apscheduler
from apscheduler.executor.pool import ProcessPoolExecutor

from apscheduler.scheduler.blocking import BlockingScheduler

from multiprocessing import get_context

context = {'mp_context': get_context('spawn')}

executor = Processpoolexecutor(max_workers=4, pool_kwargs=context)

scheduler = BlockingScheduler()

scheduler.configure(executors=executor)



Give me error Processpoolexecutor object has no attribute items
What I trying to do is to make sure worker process in spawn mode not fork mode in linux
I try change the dict value to spawn but get error str no have attribute mp_context

What python version? What apscheduler version? Please edit your question to include these details as well as the entire text of the error message so we can better help you. Otherwise what you have typed should work, so there must be something with what isn't shown.
